# ion-nav-back-button not showing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic-view

I have added this code to my index.html

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

but the back button is not showing.I also tried the alternative method putting this code in index.html

```
<ion-nav-bar ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"
  ng-click="myGoBack()">
   <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
 </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

and this in app.js

```
.controller('listController',['$scope','$http','$state','$ionicHistory',
 function($scope, $http, $state, $ionicHistory){
 $scope.myGoBack = function() {
 $ionicHistory.goBack();
 };
```

Still not showing.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<body ng-controller='mainCtrl as ctrl'>
<ion-nav-bar class="mainBar">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <a class="button button-icon">
             <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
        </a>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
      <a class="button button-icon icon" ng-click="ctrl.goMain();">
             <i class="icon ion-android-home"></i>
      </a>
      <a class="button button-icon icon" ng-click="ctrl.goProfile();">
             <i class="icon ion-android-person" ></i>
      </a>
      <a class="button button-icon icon" ng-click="ctrl.goCustomCmd();">
             <i class="icon ion-android-search"></i>
      </a>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

Also check your `$stateProvider` is well configured. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(event, viewData) {
        viewData.enableBack = true;
    });
```

inside the controller i.e. mention back button explicitely